# Public function, checking for duplicate in two columns before adding data to the table

Tags: php, sql, function, opencart

I have three column in my table as follow:

```
product_id
sku
model
```

I am trying to write a function that every time I am adding a new value to column `model` it checks to make sure this value is unique in `model` and also in `sku` with the unique `product_id` provided.
I have this function right now that checks for existing `model` before letting the `model` column addd a value. but I will need it to also check the `sku` when the `model` column is adding new value in order to make sure the new value does not currently exist neither in `model` column nor in `sku` column.

```
public function checkmodel($model, $product_id=0) {
  if (!$model) {return false; }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product` WHERE model='".$this->db->escape($model)."' AND sku='" AND product_id<>'".(int)$product_id."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->rows;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the escape of the `$model` and `$sku` values to make it easier to read; put those back in.

```
    public function checkmodel($model, $product_id=0) {
      if (!$model) {return false; }
      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product` WHERE
  (model='". $model."' OR sku='" . $model . "') 
  AND product_id != '".(int)$product_id."'";
      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      if ($query->row['total'] != 0) return false; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Scott, now the issue is no matter what the input is it give the false return, and does not pass to the true return even of the input is correct

Comment: OK.  Then please query the database (using PHPMyAdmin or however you do a direct query) with the model number/product id pairs you are testing with as follows:  `SELECT * FROM oc_product WHERE (model='your-model' OR sku = 'your-model') AND product_id != your-product-id`.  Let's see what's there.

Comment: I get empty result

Comment: when I put print statement (replacing return with print in the last if statement), It prints "true" if the input is not duplicate of any model of sku and it prints "falsetrue" if the input is a duplicate in either model or sku.

Comment: I removed the last return statement and it starts working great, I edited your answer, Thank you for your time and assistance

Comment: please remove the last return statement, (return true) the answer is not complete with that statement

Comment: OK, the change has been made.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance  :-)